# helm I cannot select a substring of the current history

Tags: helm

sometimes when I am using Meta-x I cannot select some of the options. The window in divided into "Emacs Command History", and below "Emacs Commands". But I cannot move to the "Emacs command".

This happens specifically when the command I want is a substring of commands in the "Emacs Command History". See the image I am attaching. I can select man-kill, but not man.

[image: cannot select man]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

just add a `$` sign at the end of your search string, so that your regexp match terminates there...

Comment: This helps. I didn't realize it was a regular expression. I guess precise solution is ^man$

Comment: And to move to the "Emacs commands" section just hit C-o